# How do I format the Dense Layer Input Shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

So I have been reading other posts about Dense layers and the input shape and unfortunately am just not really grasping how to adjust the input shape. I am trying to replicate a model that is here:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
import tensorflow as tf

model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape))

model.add(Dense(64,
            activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(64, 
            activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dropout(0.15))

model.compile(loss=root_mean_squared_error,
                    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate))
```

My inputs have been in batches of 168 elements with 3 features each. To my understanding (which is very limited, I've been learning what I can as I go), this would leave me with an input shape of (168,3). When I input that the error code that comes out is

```
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 3 for '{{node root_mean_squared_error/sub}} = 
Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential/dropout/dropout/Mul_1, Cast)' with input shapes: [?,168,64], [?,1,3].
```

Is there something I am missing? When I do the same thing with an LSTM model I just put the 'input_shape' variable as a parameter in the first LSTM layer. Thank you in advance for helping me and maybe pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Please update the code snippet so it's executable and then describe what's wrong with it. E.g. Why do you even want to set the input shape manually?

Comment: I was under the impression that I had to, do I not?

Comment: If you don't explicitly give it, keras will infer the input shape from the previous layer, if possible.

Comment: The input shape needs to be defined manually for the first layer.

Comment: are you sure you wanna add a dropout layer as the last layer?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(168,3)))

model.add(Dense(64,
            activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(64, 
            activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dropout(0.15))

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",
                    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))

print(model.summary())

x = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(168,3)))
y = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(168,1)))

model.fit(x=x,y=y)
```